# Can i install ubuntu on an SSD from a persistent live OS and get to keep all the data, programs and settings in the new installation?

Tags: 20.04, system-installation, live-usb, persistence, systemback

I have been trying Ubuntu 20.04 running as persistent live from a 32 GB flash drive, i have setup a lot of programs, settings and gnome extensions and have a lot of data saved there as well, that situation have been going on for more than a month so i have gotten used to the system as my daily, its been great.

Is there any way i get to fresh install the system on an SSD and get to keep all my settings programs and data etc exactly as they are? I do need to install a lot of drivers for my PC that's usually done in the OS installation process that's why i am not sure about trying Systemback as the solution.

any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You can backup your data (documents, music, etc) and restore (copy and paste) them in the installed Ubuntu system. The apps and extensions will not get installed from the persistent folder/partition when you install Ubuntu using that USB.

Comment: @user68186 yeah thats the plan if i cant figure out how to transfer my programs and settings

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to transfer your programs. Most personal settings are stored in the  `/home` folder so they can be easily copied to the new home.